# Can i write log to another machine in the network?

Tags: java, log4j, ear

I made a web app with a ServletContextListener that in its contextInitialized() just calls two methods from two jars. The jars use log4j to print logs in its execution, what is useful for me on testing. Now, I package this app in an ear file, and deploy into a WAS, that is located into a server to which I don't have access (meaning, I can't access FTP to see paths on the server, etc) to set the path for the logs in the server, and it will take some time to get actual permission to set this.

I thought that maybe I could set log4j to print the logs in my working machine (that is also connected to the network the server is connected)

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Log4j has many appenders: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html

For Log to different machine you can use SocketAppender. But for yours situation better store logs in database with  JDBCAppender

Comment: I have no database in my machine, and in the server I have access to none database, so, it'll have to be file only. Socket it is, i guess then? =S

Comment: Yes, socket can be used. In Log4j package included org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer for store log events.